# how to set Jenkins env variable with python script

Tags: python, maven, jenkins

I have a jenkins build process and i use a python script to calculate the new version:

> ```
> import string
> import os
> print 'Current version is ' + os.environ['POM_VERSION']
> versionArr = string.split(os.environ['POM_VERSION'], '.')
> versionArr[2] = str(int(versionArr[2]) + 1)
> if  int(versionArr[2]) > 100:
>     versionArr[2] = '0'
>     versionArr[1] = str(int(versionArr[1]) + 1)
> if int(versionArr[1]) > 100:
>     versionArr[0] = str(int(versionArr[0]) + 1)
>     versionArr[1] = '0'
> print  versionArr
> print 'New version will be: ' + versionArr[0] + '.' + versionArr[1] + '.' + versionArr[2]
> os.environ['NEW_POM_VERSION'] =  versionArr[0] + '.' + versionArr[1] + '.' + versionArr[2]
> ```

And then i want to run

```
versions:set -DnewVersion=${NEW_POM_VERSION} -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

on a different step. but the `${NEW_POM_VERSION}` stays the same and does not translate to the value i set.

Am i trying to call the variable in the wrong way. i also tried using `$NEW_POM_VERSION` which didn't work as well

so how am i supposed to export the variable correctly to my environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins spawns a new environment for each build step (and post-build step). Setting a value in one will not be persisted to the rest.

You need [**EnvInject plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).

- In your python script, write the final value to a properties file, in format `param=value`.
- Next, configure an **EnvInject** build step to load variables from that properties file.
- At this point, those loaded properties will be available as environment variables to all other build steps/post-build steps of this job.

Comment: I know this is a bit off topic. but the environment variable is confined with in the build process right?. There is no way i am going to change some important system variables?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole reason for spawning a separate environment for build step: so that you **cannot** mess up the system (and other running Jenkins jobs). Of course you can purposely break it, if you use `setx` or something like that.